# How do I create a custom flat world?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

On Minecraft, I am trying to make an adventure map the requires an entire world made of iron blocks. I have no clue how to edit the adventure maps besides villages, dungeons, ect. ect. If posible, could you also tell me the code I would need for a world made of iron?

Comment: Is this functionality available yet?  I haven't noticed anything in the change logs recently to suggest that it's been implemented yet.

Comment: in 1.4.2, it was added.

Comment: So it is.  Should have checked before I posted.

Comment: its okay, just came out 3 days ago

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code for your preset is as follows:

`2; 7, 63*minecraft:iron_block; 2`

`2;` To dictate the current preset parser.

`7,` For a layer of bedrock

`63*minecraft:iron_block;` For 63 layers of iron blocks

`2` For a desert biome for no rain. Other biome IDs can be found [here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Data_values#Biome_IDs)

[Source](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Superflat#Preset_code_format)

Comment: "No rain" – nice touch.